# For a property found by reflection how can I test for Listness and enumerate over it?

Tags: c#, list

How can I test whether a class member is a list when I don't know it's exact type? And how do I then iterate over it?

myc is an instance of MyClass

```
using System.Reflection;

public class MyClass {
       public sometype somename { get; set; }
       public List<double> doubles { get; set; }
       public List<string> strings { get; set; }
}

foreach(PropertyInfo pi in MyClass.GetProperties()) {

     if (pi.GetValue(myc, null) is List<???>){ <--- what should this be?

        foreach(object obj in pi.GetValue(myc, null)) { <---- doesn't work

        }
        var l = pi.GetValue(myc, null) as List<???> <---- doesn't work 
     }
}
```

Comment: Using the non-generic `IEnumerable` would be easier. I don't know if it works for your situation though.

Comment: Check to see if it implements ienumerable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you want to do is enumerate the values, you could test for the non-generic `IEnumerable` instead:

```
object value = pi.GetValue(myc, null);
IEnumerable enumerable = value as IEnumerable;
if (enumerable != null)
{
    foreach (object obj in enumerable)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that that will iterate over the characters in a string, as `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`. You may want to hard-code against that.

If you're happy with any `IList` implementation (including `List<T>`), you could substitute `IList` for `IEnumerable` above.

Note that basically this is avoiding getting into generics - detecting and using generics within reflection is a messy business.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not clear on the distinction between IList and IEnumerable but I'll go and look that up.

Comment: Hmm .. it wants a type for Enumerable :( "Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments"

Comment: @TheMathemagician Use `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, don't use the one in the generic namespace.